# Notification if something was change/created in your folder

Tags: windows, notifications

Is it possible to create notification that lets you know if something was modified, created, etc?

Comment: on Windows, you can use Directory Change Notifications: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/obtaining-directory-change-notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "emailUserName="
set "emailPassword="
set "target="
REM set "target="
REM set "target="
set "subject="
FOR %%G IN (*) DO attrib -A "%%G"
:loop
set "body="
FOR %%G IN (*) DO (
    attrib "%%G" | findstr /B /L A 1>nul
    if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
        echo "%%G"
        set "body=!body!^<br ^/^>%%G"
        attrib -A "%%G"
        )
 ) 2>nul
if not "%body%"=="" echo sending email
if not "%body%"=="" set "body=!body!" 
if not "%body%"=="" powershell.exe -command "Send-MailMessage -From '!emailUserName!' -to '!target!' -Subject '!subject!' -Body '!body!' -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer 'smtp.gmail.com' -port '587' -UseSsl -Credential (New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ('!emailUserName!', (ConvertTo-SecureString -String '!emailPassword!' -AsPlainText -Force)))"
cls
goto :loop
```

emailUserName - from which email it will be send
emailPassword - enter password
target - to whom it will be sent
subject - subject

You need to create bash script and run it at the folder where files will be created/modified. As soon as file has been create or modified it will send an email to your target.

Comment: It would be great if you could explain, in general lines, how this code does what it's meant to.

Answer (score 0):

For simple notifications, you can use [Directory Change Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/obtaining-directory-change-notifications). There's already a quite big and comprehensive example on the page and I will not write another example.

By simple notification I mean file/folder create and modification for a specific folder which shouldn't change very often.

If you want to handle system wide file/folder notification, I would suggest you to write a [file filter driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/what-is-a-file-system-filter-driver-).

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion SharePoint 2016, 2013, or 2010 fixes your problem :

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-sharepoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918

Comment: The question didn't mention SharePoint anywhere?